# Javascript throws error when trying to send var to AS3 ExternalInterface

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, externalinterface

I know there have been tons of questions about this topic already but none of them have solved my issue, perhaps I am just missing something.

Anyways, here is the deal. I have a happy little html5 game that plays some audio and sound affects etc and it works great in every browser that supports html5. However, those that don't require a flash fallback. No big deal right? Apparently not… I've made a small swf that should accept the mp3 url from JS and then get the mp3 and play it. I have to use this way as there are a lot of audio files and I would like to try and avoid making a swf file for each one.

Here is the AS - I'm using the ExternalInterface to receive the variable from js.

```
 import flash.external.*;

 ExternalInterface.addCallback("callFlash", playSound); 

 function playSound(file:String):void {
    var s:Sound = new Sound();
    s.load(new URLRequest(file));

    s.play();
 }
```

And then my JS to pass the variable:

```
 var flash = $('#fbplayer')[0];
 console.log(flash); //returns flash object so jquery is not the issue
 flash.callFlash(fallSource);
```

So theoretically everything should work fine (if I understand ExternalInterface correctly). However, the following error is thrown:

```
 TypeError: flash.callFlash is not a function
 flash.callFlash(fallSource);
```

I can't seem to find where the issue was.
I'm open to any answers or even a completely different way of doing this.
As long as it works as this is holding up the delivery of the project :C

Thanks!

Comment: Is there more than 1 flash object on the page? I ask b/c of this: `var flash = $('#fbplayer')[0];`

Comment: No only one flash object on the page but using [0] so that jQuery doesn't return an jQuery object - the [0] forces jQuery to take the object. As far as I know at least…

Comment: The only other thing that jumps out (aside from the usual `allowScriptAccess` embed param) is that perhaps the JS is calling the Flash function before `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` has been executed.

Comment: I thought of allowScriptAccess and set it to "always" which did not change anything. And I believe flash has had enough time to execute ExternalInterface as the js function that sends is linked to a click function that no matter how many times I press I still get the error. Puzzling.

Comment: This is the error Chrome spits out incase it helps.
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'callFlash' main.js:20542
playMusic main.js:20542
(anonymous function) main.js:20477
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but I've never had success finding my flash objects properly with jquery. It's better to go with a getElementById. Also, one other crazy thing I ran into with some modern browsers just a couple months ago is that I actually needed to tell flash to wait a frame after initializing any callbacks via ExternalInterface.